# Distribution of Trace values

Tags: finite-fields

I try to prove that  ${2^{n-1}}$ elements of the field $\mathbf{F}_{2^{n}}$ have  a Trace with value 1, while the other ${2^{n-1}}$ elements have a Trace with value 0.

I started to show that Trace(1) = 1, and I tried to use the additivity of the Trace but I wasn't successful. Any advice ?

Comment: "elements based..." ? Are you talking of the elements in that field? And thus their trace is just the sum of their values over that extensions Galois group?

Comment: Sorry, i meant elements if the field

Comment: Observe that $\;Tr.(1)=1\iff n\;$ is *odd* .

Comment: What happens if n is even ?

Answer (score 1):

Because $tr(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2^{n-1}$ it can take the value zero at most $2^{n-1}$ times. Because it is linear it takes the value zero at least $2^{n-1}$ times (rank-nullity tells that the kernel has dimension $\ge n-1$). Because $tr(x)$ is either zero or $1$, it has to take both values equally often.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is this explanation independent if n is even or odd ?

Comment: In the script here is a hint to prove it by additivity of the trace function. Do you have any advice how this can be used ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just linear algebra: the trace map is a linear functional $\;\Bbb F_{2^n}\to\Bbb F_2\;$, and since the extension $\;\Bbb F_{2^n}/\Bbb F_2\;$ is separable it is **not** the zero functional (or just show there's some element with trace different from zero), from where it follows that it  is onto (this much is true for *any* linear functional over *any* vector space) and thus $\;\dim\ker\,Tr.=n-1\;$, and this means that

$$|\ker Tr.|=|\Bbb F_{2^{n-1}}|=2^{n-1}$$

and we're done.